# Как через upstart от обычного юзера выполнить service myapp start?

Tags: linux

От рута у меня команда `service myapp start` работает. Но от обычного юзера ругается: `myapp: unrecognized service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

краткий ответ: никак.

потому что запуск/остановка «демонов» — это прерогатива root-а.

получить root-овые полномочия «обычный пользователь» может, например, с помощью `su` или `sudo`.